Apache2 - Prevent access to .php files if the php module is not enabled or in any case in which the php files are not parsed
I would like to prevent php files from being displayed in case they are not parsed as php, in Apache2.
For example, at the moment, if there's a failure in mod_php or its configuration, the files would be displayed as plain text and the source code would be visible.
Alternatively, if the mod_proxy module is disabled (or bugged) and we're using php-fpm, the source code would also be visible.
I'm looking for some suggestions to harden the configuraiton to prevent the leakage of the source code in case something ever goes wrong. I am aware that it's a highly unlikely case, but I'd rather be safe than sorry and I do believe that if this is possible, it should be the default configuration.
